# Openlayers custom (local) OSM tiles layer with limited extent

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, extents

I know, how to add an overlay layer by specifying my own URL. But what if the overlay layer extent is not as large as base layer - e.g. overlay layer is only avaliable for one country and not for the whole world.

```
  new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("My custom local overlay layer",
  ["http://a.tile.myserver.org/maps/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
  "http://b.tile.myserver.org/maps/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
  "http://c.tile.myserver.org/maps/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"]);
```

How can I pass parameter, that OL would not seek for the tiles, that does not exist - that are outside of the avaliable layer extent (outside that country)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches that could be used. The first one is more like what you are trying to achieve.

**Option 1: Layer max extent**

You can set the `maxExtent` property for the layer along with the `displayOutsideMaxExtent` property to prevent OpenLayers from requesting tiles that would fall outside the maximum extent. If you don't specify a maximum extent for a layer then it adopts the extent of the base layer. You could change your code to create the layer to include these properties:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("My custom local overlay layer",
["http://a.tile.myserver.org/maps/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
"http://b.tile.myserver.org/maps/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
"http://c.tile.myserver.org/maps/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
{
  maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds([left, bottom, right, top]),
  displayOutsideMaxExtent: false
});
```

If the user zooms or pans outside the `maxExtent` for the layer the OpenLayers will not request tiles.

**Option 2: Pan and zoom restriction**

You simply need to set the `restrictedExtent` property for your map. This can either be an `OpenLayers.Bounds` object or an `Array`. If you specify an `Array` then it must be of the form `[left, bottom, right, top]`. For example;

```
map.restrictedExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(left, bottom, right, top));
```

Or

```
map.restrictedExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds([left, bottom, right, top]));
```

Or

```
map.restrictedExtent([left, bottom, right, top]);
```

In each case `map` being a reference to your map. The default for `restrictedExtent` is `null` in which case OpenLayers uses the extents of the base layer. Setting `restrictedExtent` overrides this behaviour and instead OpenLayers will not allow zooming or panning outside the specified extents.

Comment: Hmm. But I want to be able to display whole world, and put overlay only over that area. Doesn't restrictedExtent restrict panning a map outsite that area?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I have updated my answer to include that use case too.